# How to add styleSet to Sonata admin formatter & Ivory CKeditor

Tags: ckeditor, symfony, sonata-admin

I've been scouring the docs and am unable to find what I'm after, which is  adding the heading & styles config to the ckeditor inside of sonata admin.

I would like to be able to add some heading & styled elements to my richtext configs but am unable to do so.  I've tried the following:

- Adding stylesSet to ivory_ck_editor in config.yml
- Adding the ckeditor_toolbar_icons parameter to the richtext itself

My admin field definition:

`->add('body', 'sonata_simple_formatter_type', array('format' => 'richhtml'
))`

ckeditor always looks like this, despite what I have tried: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkcIn.png

Can anyone link me to a working example of adding the style options to sonata admin's formatter?

Versions:

`"symfony/symfony": "3.2.*",
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.10",
"sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "^3.1",`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add the specific option ckeditor_toolbar_icons:

```
        ->add('abstractEn', 'sonata_simple_formatter_type', array(
            'format' => 'richhtml',
            'ckeditor_toolbar_icons' => array(
                1 => array('Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline',
                    '-', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord',
                    '-', 'Undo', 'Redo',
                    '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent',
                    '-', 'Blockquote',
                    '-', 'Image', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Table'),
                2 => array('Maximize', 'Source'),
                3 => array('Styles','Format','Font','FontSize')
            )
        ))
```

Third element of array activates styles and other formatting Stuff.

Be sure to clear your cache anyway